# Solving $2^{-x} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \sqrt{x} +1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to solve the following for my Algebra 2 class: $$2^{-x} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \sqrt{x} +1.$$ I tried to isolate $x$, but I keep ending up with $\log x$ or $x$ in an exponent as the value for $x$. I know that $x$ is $0$, but I don't know how to go about to solve it algebraically.

Comment: $x=0$ is a pretty obvious answer.

Comment: Yeah. I understand that, but I need to solve it algebraically to receive credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side is a decreasing function and the right hand side an increasing function.

Both are continuous and $x = 0$ is a trivial solution. Hence it is the unique solution.

More formally, consider :
$$f(x) = 2^{-x} - \frac13\sqrt{x} - 1$$

Taking first derivative you show that it is a strictly decreasing continuous function. $f(0) = 0$ hence $f(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $2^{-x}$ decreases but the function  $\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \sqrt{x} +1$ increases. So there is only one answer: $x=0$. You also could plot these functions to see that.